# VB.net: How to change amp; to &

Tags: html, vb.net, json, json.net

I have a json feed for songs, and for some songs it shows an `amp;` when in the json it's `&amp;` Here's an example of a title in the the json:

> Stay (Bass King &amp; X-Vertigo Mix) (feat. Mikky Ekko)

I think the json was intended for the internet.
Then it will get rid of the & and keep amp;. How do I stop this?

Comment: What do you mean then "then it get rid of the & and keep amp;? When? What system is processing the data at this point? What you are seeing an called an xml (or html) [**entity**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references). It's (sort of) normal to see those in certain kinds of feeds, and certain readers (like html parsers) should handle it correctly automatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a reference to System.Web and you can use

[`System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlDecode()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.htmldecode.aspx)

Example:

```
Dim x As String = "Stay (Bass King &amp; X-Vertigo Mix) (feat. Mikky Ekko)"
Console.WriteLine(x)
x = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(x)
Console.WriteLine(x)
```

Output:

```
Stay (Bass King &amp; X-Vertigo Mix) (feat. Mikky Ekko)
Stay (Bass King & X-Vertigo Mix) (feat. Mikky Ekko)
```

Comment: Thank you for that answer. It was also the labels settings